# Load SQL Connection Str in Asp.net Core 2 / EF Core 2

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.0

In Asp.Net.Core.v1 in the inherited DbContextClass I loaded connection string from appsettings.json like this:

```
private IConfigurationRoot _config;
public MainDbContext(IConfigurationRoot config, DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
{
    _config = config;
}

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_config["Data:SQLConnectionString"]);
}
```

with all the config changes in v2, this is now a run-time error.

How do I load/use the SQL DB connection string in EFCore.v2 from appsettings.*.json ?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the example at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro
in sections
Create the Database Context
and 
Register the context with dependency injection

Note: the name "ConnectionStrings" in JSON is significant

Answer (score 0):

do it like this

```
private IConfigurationRoot _config;
public MainDbContext(IConfigurationRoot config, DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
{
    _config = config;
}

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_config["Data:SQLConnectionString"]);
}
```

## simply remove: `base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);`